# Pass argv[1] as a parameter to pthread_create.

Tags: c, pthreads, void-pointers, arrays

I am trying to create a thread that takes the character string form `argv[1]` and passes it to my function. This is the code I am trying to use to pass it.

```
if(pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, getMax, &argv[1]) != 0){
    printf("ERROR createing the thread\n");
    return 1;
}
```

This is my function that i am calling in the pthread_create function.

```
void * getMax(void * f){
char * fileName = (char*)f;
printf("%s\n\n",fileName);
}
```

I believe my problem is when I am casting it back to a character pointer. The `printf` function prints out a couple of random characters. If I call the function passing in a string it works.

```
pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, getMax, "This Works");
```

If someone could explain how to cast the `argv[1]` so that it behaves like a character array that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `&argv[1]` is the address of a `char*`, not a `char*`. Just pass `argv[1]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that `&argv[1]` is a `char*[]`, i.e. an array of pointers to characters. Casting it to a `char *` i.e. pointer to characters is incorrect.

Try:

```
pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, getMax, argv[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that did not solve my problem. I get a compiler warranting stating it is making a pointer from integer without a cast. When I ran the program I got a segmentation fault 11.

Comment: I had a different error in my main method that was causing the error. Your suggestion helped. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the slow follow-up, glad everything works now! Happy to help!